# KVM: Can not destroy VM (Permission denied) - AppArmor blocking Libvirt

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt, apparmor

Every time I run `virsh destroy ${KVM}` as root I get the following error (`virsh shutdown ${KVM}` is showing absolutely no reaction, nothing happens):

```
error: Failed to destroy domain ${KVM}
error: Failed to terminate process 11956 with SIGTERM: Permission denied
```

When I run `shutdown -h now` inside the KVM, it hangs forever until I kill the qemu-system-x86_64 process (`kill ${PID_OF_QEMU_PROCESS}`). As stated in the syslog, apparmor is blocking the calls (both for `virsh shutdown` and `virsh destroy`):

```
apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="/usr/sbin/libvirtd" pid=23212
    comm="libvirtd" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="unconfined"
```

In the qemu configuration file `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` I tried to disable Apparmor (`security_driver = "none"`), but I still get the same error.

Some details: OS = `Debian 9`, Kernel = `4.14.0-0.bpo.2-amd64`, libvirt-version = `3.0.0-4`.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem without disabling apparmor?

Comment: Maybe stopping it first would make a difference?

Comment: Same situation with `shutdown` - I edited my question. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `security_driver = "none"` will not disable apparmor in the kernel, just some support in `libvirt` itself

Looking at the apparmor profile in current stable (debian 9/stretch) and the one currently in unstable, I see quite some differences.

I believe you could add the following rule in `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.libvirtd` (this is one of the many differences between the two versions):

```
ptrace (trace) peer=unconfined,
```

And then restart the apparmor service with `service restart apparmor`

Other rules would probably be needed to make everything work though.

An other solution would be to set the profile in "complain" mode with `aa-complain /usr/sbin/libvirtd`, that will prevent apparmor from denying anything but you would keep the issues logged.

You could later use `aa-logprof` to generate the missing rules (after **carefully reviewing** them) or try to get the apparmor profile files from unstable.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I took the usr.sbin.libvirt profile from unstable and also the /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu template. Now it works fluently.

Comment: That should maybe be reported in Debian

Comment: This has been fixed in stretch-proposed-updates https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882697#80